# How to save selected element from combobox as variable in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm interested in how to save a selected value from my combobox as variable, so when I press e.g. B then I want it to be saved as SelectedValueCBox = selected value, which would be B in this case.
Thank you for your help

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class App(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.title = "PyQt5 - StockWindow"
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 200
        self.height = 300
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title) 
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height) 
        self.tab_widget = MyTabWidget(self) 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget) 
        self.show() 

class MyTabWidget(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        #self.layout = QGridLayout(self) 
        self.tabs = QTabWidget() 
        self.tab1 = QWidget() 
        self.tabs.resize(300, 200) 
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Stock-Picker") 
        self.tab1.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        button = QToolButton()
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(button, 1,1,1,1)

        d = {'AEX':['A','B','C'], 'ATX':['D','E','F'], 'BEL20':['G','H','I'], 'BIST100':['J','K','L']}

        def callback_factory(k, v):
           return lambda: button.setText('{0}_{1}'.format(k, v))

        menu = QMenu()
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(menu, 1,1,1,1)
        for k, vals in d.items():
            sub_menu = menu.addMenu(k)
            for v in vals:
                action = sub_menu.addAction(str(v))
                action.triggered.connect(callback_factory(k, v))
            button.setMenu(menu)
      
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confused. First of all, there's no combobox in your code, are you talking about the menu you're setting on the QToolButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already returning a lambda for the connection, the solution is to use a function instead.

```
class MyTabWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # ...
        def callback_factory(k, v):
            def func():
                self.selectedValueCBox = v
                button.setText('{0}_{1}'.format(k, v))
            return func

        # ...
        self.selectedValueCBox = None
```

Note that your code also has many issues.

First of all, you should not add the menu to the layout: not only it doesn't make any sense (the menu should pop up, while adding it to a layout makes it "embed" into the widget, and that's not good), but it also creates graphical issues especially because you added the menu to the same grid "slot" (1, 1, 1, 1) which is already occupied by the button.

Creating a layout with a widget as argument automatically sets the layout to that widget. While in your case it doesn't create a big issue (since you've already set the layout) you should not create `self.tab1.layout` with `self`. Also, since you've already set the `QVBoxLayout` (due to the parent argument), there's no need to call `setLayout()` again.

A widget container makes sense if you're actually going to add more than one widget. You're only adding a QTabWidget to its layout, so it's almost useless, and you should just subclass from QTabWidget instead.

Calling `resize` on a widget that is going to be added on a layout is useless, as the layout will take care of the resizing and the previous resize call will be completely ignored. `resize()` makes only sense for top level widgets (windows) or the rare case of widgets not managed by a layout.

`self.layout()` is an [*existing property*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layout) of all QWidgets, you should not overwrite it. The same with `self.width()` and `self.height()` you used in the `App` class.

`App` should refer to an *application* class, but you're using it for a QMainWindow. They are radically different types of classes.

Finally, you have no combobox in your code. A combobox is widget that is completely different from a drop down menu like the one you're using. I suggest you to be more careful with the terminology in the future, otherwise your question would result very confusing, preventing people to actually being able to help you.

Comment: How do you mean, that the code has many issues? I copied the code, from a previous question by another user and changed some variables so that it fits to my programme (it is a programme for stock analysing). This is only a part of my whole code. This is the first tab of the tabwidget, and I have to save the pressed element as a variable, in order to be able to show in another tab the charts.

Comment: Thanks it helped, btw. I copied the code, because I have no idea how to create a nested ComboBox with PyQt5. I'm more familiar to Tkinter.

Comment: It doesn't matter if that's your own code or someone else's, the point is that there were lots of issues and I listed them. The fact that you're adding other tabs doesn't change the fact that subclassing a QWidget that is going to contain only one QTabWidget is useless. And, again, what you've done is a menu, not a combobox; the fact that its behavior is "slightly" similar to a combobox because it has a popup list to select item from is pointless: they are completely different widgets.

Comment: Ok, but how would you then create a nested combobox?

Comment: A combo box is not intended for hierarchical structures, but anyway you could create a tree model (using a QStandardItemModel), create a QTreeView and use [`setView()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setView) to set it as the popup of the QComboBox. I suggest you to study the documentation about all those classes, try it on your own and eventually create a new question about it if you are still not able to get it as you want. Note that by "what you've done is not a combobox" doesn't mean that what you're doing is wrong: my objection is about the *name* of what you're using.